# Bind a condition to a model in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-1.3

```
<?php
   class User extends AppModel {
var $name = 'User';
var $displayField = 'fname';
```

}

How can I only return users from this model that have a "standing" of "1"? I am not looking to do this from the controller but, from the model.

[Solution] In model

```
function beforeFind($queryData){
    $queryData['conditions']['standing'] = 1;
    return $queryData;
}
```

Comment: For what call? For all `find` calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to put in some filtering conditions in your `beforeFind` callback. Modifying the `$queryData` variable and adding your restriction to the `conditions` key should do it.

From the manual entry - http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1049/beforeFind

> Called before any find-related operation. The $queryData passed to
>   this callback contains information about the current query:
>   conditions, fields, etc.
>
> If you do not wish the find operation to begin (possibly based on a
>   decision relating to the $queryData options), return false. Otherwise,
>   return the possibly modified $queryData, or anything you want to get
>   passed to find and its counterparts.
>
> You might use this callback to restrict find operations based on a
>   user’s role, or make caching decisions based on the current load.